# Insert some rows in database by index DevExpress

Tags: c#, devexpress

I have some problem with my code. 
Before the program code add in DB only 1 row (selected row) after clikcking on button. Now, i remade this code, and need add some CHECKED rows in database, by index of this rows. Error in this row -

> MyCommonClass.prSrvObject.SaveRequest(dsRequests, out iErrId, out sErrMsg);

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>();
int i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < MyCommonClass.OraDataSet.Tables["Table1"].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    object asd = MyCommonClass.OraDataSet.Tables["Tale1"].Rows[i]["CHECK_STATUS"];
    if (!(asd is DBNull))
    {
        Convert.ToBoolean(asd);
        myList.Add(i);
    }
}

if ((myList.Count > 0) && (RequestActionId == 7))
{
    for (i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
    {
        DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
        ds1.Tables.Add(MyCommonClass.OraDataSet.Tables["table1"].Clone());

        DataRow drNew = ds1.Tables["table1"].NewRow();
        DataRow drSrc = MyCommonClass.OraDataSet.Tables["table1"].Rows[i];
        MyCommonClass.CopyRow(drSrc, drNew);

        drNew["Req_Action_Id"] = RequestActionId;
        drNew["Update_Login"] = MyCommonClass.prSrvObject.GetSecurityPermission().Tables["TUsers"].Rows[0]["User_Name"].ToString();
        drNew["Update_User_FIO"] = MyCommonClass.prSrvObject.GetSecurityPermission().Tables["TUsers"].Rows[0]["User_Fio"].ToString();
        ds1.Tables["table1"].Rows.Add(drNew);
        drNew.AcceptChanges();

        if (drSrc.RowState == DataRowState.Added) drNew.SetAdded();
        else if (drSrc.RowState == DataRowState.Modified || drSrc.RowState == DataRowState.Unchanged)
            drNew.SetModified();

        int iErrId = 0;
        string sErrMsg = string.Empty;

        //foreach (DataRow ds in ds1.Tables["table1"].Rows)
        //{
        //for (i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
        //{
        MessageBox.Show("1");
        //Сохраняем заявку
        MyCommonClass.prSrvObject.SaveRequest(ds1, out iErrId, out sErrMsg);
        MessageBox.Show("2");
        if (iErrId != 0) throw new Exception(sErrMsg);
        MessageBox.Show("3");

        ds1 = MyCommonClass.prSrvObject.GetRequests(Convert.ToInt32(drSrc["Req_Id"].ToString()),
            out iErrId, out sErrMsg);

        if (iErrId != 0) throw new Exception(sErrMsg);
        //} 
        foreach (DataRow Row in MyCommonClass.OraDataSet.Tables["RequestActions"].Select("Req_Id = " + drSrc["Req_Id"].ToString()))
        {
            Row.AcceptChanges();
            Row.Delete();
            Row.AcceptChanges();
        }
        if (!(ds1.Tables["table1"] == null || ds1.Tables["table1"].Rows.Count == 0))
        {
            MyCommonClass.CopyRow(ds1.Tables["table1"].Rows[myList[i]], drSrc);
            drSrc.AcceptChanges();
            //grvRequest.RefreshRow(); //grvRequest.FocusedRowHandle
            //grvRequest.RefreshRow(grvRequest.GetSelectedRows()[0]);

            //DataRow drNew = ds1.Tables["table1"].NewRow();
            //ds1.Tables.Add(MyCommonClass.OraDataSet.Tables["table1"].Clone());
            //DataRow drSrc = MyCommonClass.OraDataSet.Tables["table1"].Rows[i];

            foreach (DataRow Row in ds1.Tables["RequestActions"].Select())
            {
                drNew = MyCommonClass.OraDataSet.Tables["RequestActions"].NewRow();
                MyCommonClass.CopyRow(Row, drNew);
                MyCommonClass.OraDataSet.Tables["RequestActions"].Rows.Add(drNew);
                drNew.AcceptChanges();
            }
            grvDetailView.RefreshData();
        }
        else
        {
            //DataRow drRow = grvRequest.GetDataRow(grvRequest.GetSelectedRows()[0]);
            DataRow drRow = MyCommonClass.OraDataSet.Tables["table1"].Rows[i];

            drRow.AcceptChanges();
            drRow.Delete();
            drRow.AcceptChanges();
        }

        XtraMessageBox.Show("text",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

    }
}
```

Comment: What exception being thrown on the corresponding line? Please add more info by providing exception details (seems that code using WinForms).

Comment: cannot update database, because sql&rownum = 0

Comment: This error from database, VS hasn't error. When i was debbuging, after row MyCommonClass.prSrvObject.SaveRequest(dsRequests, out iErrId, out sErrMsg); stop working.